# Split string with optional substring

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, python-3.6

Here, `_also` is optional, how to split string making `_also` as optional?

```
>>> aa="may_be_this.is_the_string"
>>> aa.split('this.')[1]
'is_the_string'
>>>
>>> aa="may_be_this_also.is_the_string"
>>> aa.split('this[_also]*.')[1] # something like this, to make _also as optional substring.
```

Comment: How would `"may_be_this_also_also.is_the_string"` work out? (two _also's)

Comment: `'this[_also]*.'` will split at `'textlike_this_____aaaalllssooooooJuhu'` to `['text','uhu']` - is that supposed to be happening?

Comment: What's the expected output for `"may_be_this_also.is_the_string"` ?

Comment: @DeveshKumarSingh, `is_the_string`

Comment: okay, what about the other outputs the commentors pointed out? like `"may_be_this_also_also.is_the_string"` and `'textlike_this_____aaaalllssooooooJuhu'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A general split regex like this

`this(?:_also)*\.`

which has a required `this`
followed by a many opotional `_also`
followed by a literal dot `.`

Nothing is captured, so this info is excluded as elements.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking at [re.split](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.split)

```
In [21]: import re                                                                                    

In [22]: aa="may_be_this_also.is_the_string"                                                          

In [23]: re.split('this(_also)+.', aa)                                                                
Out[23]: ['may_be_', 'is_the_string']

In [24]: aa="may_be_this.is_the_string"                                                               

In [25]: re.split('this.', aa)                                                                        
Out[25]: ['may_be_', 'is_the_string']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use regxes to split:

You should mask literal `'.'` in your pattern - else `'.'` stands for anything. You can use a non grouping `(?:....)` to add an optional pattern if you attribute it with `?` (== 0 or 1 occurence):

```
import re

aa = "may_be_this.is_the_string"
print(re.split(r'this\.',aa))           # 'this' and literal '.'

bb = "may_be_this_also.is_the_string"
print(re.split(r'this(?:_also)?\.',bb)) # 'this' and optional '_also' and literal '.'
```

Output:

```
['may_be_', 'is_the_string']
['may_be_', 'is_the_string']
```

Using `'[_also]*'` allows 0..n occurences of all the characters inside the [...] - probably not what you want.

Using *raw strings* is a good habit to aquire for specifying regex patterns.

You might want to read [regex-info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/regex/info) - it is a lot but covers the basics. To test regexes I would like to endorse http://www.regex101.com too you - it has the python dialect and explains regexes in clear text.